# Design: a table view controller before a tab bar ?

Tags: ios, iphone

A general design question.
Is it a good design to have a table view controller for the first view, in which all the view controllers of a tab bar will be presented ?
Or is it a good design to have a table view controller as the first controller in the tab bar, in which all the view controllers will  be presented?
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about UX. You might have better luck over at [our UX site](http://ux.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

I think the latter is better. Because it seems to be more close to the design of iTunes Store in iPhones and users will already be familiar to using it.